# Return a Flux from Mono's in Controller quest

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I want to send the partials results in the response based on two client's requests. I'm using the `Flux.concat` method to combine the Monos. But, when I receive the first result and use the `sink.next` method to send the result into response, the Flux creation is completed and I lost the second result to send into the response. How I can complete the Flux only when I receive all results from the client's requests?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/movies/{name}", produces = {MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE})
public Flux<String> search(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    return this.movieService.search(name);
}

public class MovieService {

private final ClientA clientA;

private final ClientB clientB;

public Flux<String> search(String name) {
    Mono<String> monoA = this.clientA.search(name);

    Mono<String> monoB = this.clientB.search(name);


    return Flux.create(sink -> {
        Flux.concat(monoA, monoB).subscribe(value -> {
            log.info("Value {}", value);
            sink.next(value);
            sink.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dont use subscribe, the calling client is the subscriber, you application is the producer. Remove Flux.create and just return the result of Flux.concat

Comment: Thanks. Now I can receive all responses. But, I know that the first call is faster than second client call. I want to send results when I receive the response. Using only the concant, I will send the responses only when I received all responses from clients. So the second call is blocking the first call. How can I fix this?

Comment: Here you can read about all the different ways there are too many to sit here and explain each and everyone of them. https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-combine-streams

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I read the article, but I didn't found any method to help me to send the results based on clients' responses sequence, all methods send the response to controller only when the all client's requests have been completed. Maybe is not possible to send partial results, I guess. Right? Thanks.